# What guidelines, if any, exist to guide the DM in establishing difficulty level for skill/ability checks?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, difficulty-class

Reading through the [Basic Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/BasicRules_Playerv3.4.pdf), there is a DC Check difficulty table found on page 58:

[image: DC Table]

… but aside from the basic description of what a check is and the basic mechanics (d20 + mod/skill + any situational modifiers vs. DC) there are no guidelines for how a DM should assign DC levels to various tasks. Are there any guidelines outside of the Basic Rules that could inform 5e DMs?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: The Starter Set rulebook doesn't have 58 pages (and the LMOP adventure barely has that many). The asker seems to have meant the [basic rules PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/BasicRules_Playerv3.4.pdf), which does contain that table on p. 58.

Comment: @V2Blast Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes, in the Starter Set.

In the introduction section of the *Lost Mines of Phandelver* there is a primer section for new DMs which includes descriptions of what type of activities would make up the Easy, Moderate, and Hard DC check levels.

> - **Easy (DC 10).** An easy task requires a minimal level of competence or a modicum of luck to accomplish.
> - **Moderate (DC 15).** A moderate task requires a slightly higher level of competence to accomplish. A character with a combination of natural aptitude and specialized training can accomplish a moderate task more often than not.
> - **Hard (DC 20).** Hard tasks include any effort that is beyond the capabilities of most people without aid or exceptional ability. Even with aptitude and training, a character needs some amount of luck—or a lot of specialized training—to pull off a hard task.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning its advice for easier and harder tasks is to just say yes/no.

Comment: Do you want to include the point that one need not restrict one's self to multiples of 5 in setting DC's?