# Does this character concept involving never taking a long rest and converting spell slots to sorcery points (aka coffeelock) violate RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, warlock, sorcerer

Does the following, very cheesy character concept, violate any RAW? Please cite rules or official rulings in your answer. (Apart from RAW, I expect my DM to disallow or limit the concept, in the interest of balance. That is *not* part of my question.)

Elf. Multiclass: Sorcerer 2+ / Warlock 1+ / Bard 1

- Never takes a long rest. Ever. See question, [Must 5e elves take a long rest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78871/must-5e-elves-take-a-long-rest) Specifically, whether adventuring or not, she makes sure that every 8 hour block includes more than 2 hours of combat or strenuous activity, to ensure that no interpretation of long rest rules would allow a long rest to be automatically triggered.
- Converts warlock spell slots into sorcery points. See [@JeremyECrawford's tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/596193607595401216).
- Converts sorcery points into sorcery spell slots (or into *spellcasting* spell slots, once also multiclassing Bard) via [Flexible Casting](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#h-Flexible%20Casting)
- Spell slots created from sorcery points disappear upon long rest, as per [Flexible Casting](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#h-Flexible%20Casting) and a [tweet from @JeremyECrawford](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/03/23/sorcerer-downtime/); therefore these created spell slots will not disappear until used, e.g. for a character taking no long rests
- Spell slots created from sorcery points are *in addition to*, and not *restoration of* the sorcerer's spell slots which refresh on a long rest. This is not 100% clear from RAW or clarifications. But:
  (a) Flexible Casting uses the phrase, "additional Spell Slots";
  (b) the rule stating that created spell slots disappear on long rests is superfluous if created spell slots can only replace expended spell slots -- to have meaning it must be possible to create spell slots which are not replacements;
  (c) flexible casting does not use the word "recover", which is the word used for wizards' [Arcane Recovery](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wizard#h-Arcane%20Recovery)
- Restores warlock spell slots on a *short rest*, and repeats the cycle above, converting warlock spell slots to sorcery points to sorcerer (or *spellcasting*) spell slots
- During periods of downtime, takes as many short rests per day as permissible, to build up a stockpile of created sorcerer spell slots
- Stockpiling requires using bonus actions out of combat, [discussed elsewhere](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53935/can-a-bonus-action-be-used-outside-of-a-combat-encounter)
- Stockpiling requires having short rests on downtime days, discussed in a comment below
- While adventuring, during combat, uses created spell slots to cast spells, and/or uses flexible casting to convert those spell slots back into sorcery points
- While adventuring, after combat, will use created spell slots with Bard spells to restore hits points, since restoring hit points via long rest is unavailable, and via hit dice is mostly unavailable

I'm pretty sure this is not RAI, but does it violate RAW in some way?

Comment: Won't you have to worry about exhaustion levels?

Comment: Note that per [the latest errata](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), a character must actually sleep for 6 hours in order for a long rest to occur. Whether elves' trance also satisfies this updated requirement, I do not know.

Comment: @DanHenderson it does. 4h of elf trance is the equivalent of 8 hours of sleep. And a long rest.

Comment: Similar to @DanHenderson's point, Xanathar's Guide to Everything has new guidelines on what happens if you do not get a long rest that may make many answers here outdated (though that, as well as all other DM tools in that book, is optional).

Comment: Part of our [fine cheese collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7218/23970).

Comment: FWIW, the "coffeelock" per se seems to be a Warlock 2 Sorcerer X build (bard is almost irrelevant, but could fit in); there is a pretty solid basis for that model of this exploit, [an example of which is here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=22600207&postcount=11) ... not sure if you want to update the question or leave it as is.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to "charge up" a sorcerer/warlock by taking multiple short rests?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106255) and [Can I use Pact Magic spell slots gained on a short rest to gain sorcery points?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101813)

Comment: Can be worth taking more than 2 in warlock, for the increased income.  Also, a level 20 sorceror can technically do this without any levels in warlock at all, with Sorcerous Restoration.  It's just a bit on the slow side.

Answer (score 48):

The big issue with this seems to rely on being able to stockpile spell slots through short rests during downtime. Unfortunately, in the Resting rules (page 67 of the basic rules), it states:

> Adventurers can take short rests in the midst of an adventuring day and a long rest to end the day.

This leads me to believe that RAW, characters cannot take short rests during Downtime days and so the theoretical character has no chance to stockpile spell slots.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38608/discussion-on-answer-by-weaveworker89-how-does-this-cheesy-character-concept-vio).

Answer (score 39):

This no longer works under RAW, due to wording changes in later printings. Once your elf uses the Trance feature for four hours, they satisfy the conditions for a long rest, and thus take a long rest.

The recent [errata change](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf), due to updated wording in the PHB, clarifies how long rests now work:

> ***Long Rest (p. 186).*** The first sentence of the rule now reads, “A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, during which a character sleeps for at least 6 hours and performs no more than 2 hours of light activity, such as reading, talking, eating, or standing watch.”
>
> In addition, you regain at least one Hit Die when you  finish a long rest.

The [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) clarifies how this interacts with an elf's Trance trait:

> **Does the Trance trait allow an elf to finish a long rest in 4 hours?** If an elf meditates during a long rest (as described in the Trance trait), the elf finishes the rest after only 4 hours. A meditating elf otherwise follows all the rules for a long rest; only the duration is changed. [This answer
> has been altered as a result of a tweak to the rules for a long rest, which appears in newer printings of the *Player’s Handbook*.]

Comment: Notably, non-elves can sleep for 6 hours (which is not explicitly enough to avoid exhaustion, but I would argue is implicitly), and then make sure they do non-light activity for enough time surrounding sleeping - so playing a non-elf solves this problem.

Comment: @Vigil exhaustion occurs as a result of not taking a long rest, which means a non-elf wouldn't be able to carry off this coffeelock build. It explicitly relied on the elf's trance feature.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about meditating. It actually looks like they never trance at all. This answer seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @DCShannon actually it does by linking to the "Must 5e elves take a long rest?" Question which is inherently about the Trance feature. The elf's Trance feature was inherent to making the coffeelock work (due to getting the benefits of sleeping but not long resting and thus avoiding exhaustion but not losing the sorcery points)

Comment: @illustro There are pages of related information there, but it's not clear which, if any, interpretation the question is interested in. Anyway, it doesn't matter. All it says is that they don't rest. Ever. So this whole answer is invalid if they don't trance for four hours, which they won't, because that would be resting.

Comment: @DCShannon The elves pre-errata trance feature interaction with Long Resting was inherent to the coffeelock working, as without it the character would die from exhaustion after 6 days. The errata of the long rests and it's new interaction with this feature very specifically makes this whole build not work, as the character loses the scorcery points or they die.

Comment: @illustro If the problem is they die of exhaustion, then that's a completely different answer. It's nowhere in this answer. Also, there's a way to get around it at higher levels, as another answer points out: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/118780/12011

Comment: @DCShannon We'll have to agree to disagree here. The fundamental mechanic that made the build work no longer works and therefore the build is no longer possible. That is what this answer is about and how it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 33):

Not necessarily a violation, but a concern, which I noticed thanks to [Weaveworker89’s comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78918/how-does-this-cheesy-character-concept-violate-raw/78926?noredirect=1#comment177301_78926), that may affect this character’s ability to maintain this approach:

> Adventurers can take [...] a long rest to end the day.

Long rests are what end an adventuring day. Without them, an adventuring day never ends, and thus a new day (including, e.g., a downtime day) doesn’t begin.

This means that the character, should he wish to maintain and/or grow his stockpile of spells, must remain constantly in “adventure mode.” He cannot take advantage of any downtime-only activities.

This *does* address the problem raised by [Weaveworker89’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78926/4563): since the character is eternally “in the midst of an [endless] adventuring day,” he can always take short rests, even if we stipulate that short rests cannot happen on a downtime day.

Comment: It says "Adventurers **can** take..." It doesn't necessarily mean they **must**.

Comment: @Adeptus Except that nothing else in the rules indicates any other way to end the day, which means yes, they must, because it’s the only available way.

Comment: I disagree with your reading of this. They *can* take a long rest to end the adventuring day, not they *must* take a long rest to end the adventuring day.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Sure, they are not required to. But if they don’t, the adventuring day doesn’t end—because nothing else says it can end the adventuring day.

Comment: @KRyan Sure there is. They just ... *stop adventuring*.

Answer (score 17):

### New (optional) RAW Makes It Possible, But Expensive

As CTWind mentions in a comment on the original question, since this question was originally asked Xanathar's Guide to Everything set out new optional rules for going without a long rest.

> GOING WITHOUT A LONG REST...
>
> Whenever you end a 24-hour period without finishing a long rest, you
>   must succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or suffer one level
>   of exhaustion.
>
> It becomes harder to fight off exhaustion if you stay awake for
>   multiple days. After the  first 24 hours, the DC increases by 5 for
>   each consecutive 24-hour period without a long rest. The DC resets to
>   10 when you  finish a long rest. (XGtE: p.78)

If your DM decides to follow this rule, that means that within a short time (a week for most possible characters), you will begin to gain a level of exhaustion every day that you do not take a long rest, regardless of how well you roll on a Constitution Saving Throw. And if six levels of exhaustion are accrued, your character will die (PHB, p. 291).

Note that at sufficiently high levels your strategy can still be a net-gain, with some modifications. This rule can only produce one level of exhaustion each day. And 7 Sorcery Points can create a  5th level spell slot. And if you were a Divine Soul sorcerer (XGtE, p. 50) you can learn the 5th level spell Greater Restoration at 9th level, which removes a level of exhaustion. If you were a Divine Soul Sorcerer 9+/Warlock 3+ you could produce 4 Sorcery Points per short rest, and thus could generate enough Sorcery Points in a day to cast Greater Restoration once each day, and still have enough sorcery points left over to generate other useful spell slots.

Unfortunately, this strategy will require at least 100 gold pieces worth of diamond dust every day, which can quickly deplete an adventurer's supply if used during downtime. But it is still a possible option within the rules.

Comment: What about Aspect of the Moon?  The one that gives you "you don't need to sleep".

Comment: @Stackstuck The lack of a need for sleep does not negate the need for a "long rest" (the rules on Aspect of the Moon dictate how you can take a long rest without sleeping). And that is precisely what the rule cited above deals with.

Answer (score 3):

### This does not technically violate RAW, but if you never rest, you get tired.

So, first, the combo as described works, technically.  The problem is that it works by never ending the adventuring day, and Long Rest resets more than just your hit dice and spell slots.

In particular, the overland travel rules are per day.  More specifically, the Forced March rules make clear that Overland Travel is assuming 8 hours of movement per day and that if you go beyond that, you start developing levels of Exhaustion.  You can fend off that exhaustion with Con saves, but the DC on those saves go up with every hour past the 8 that you march.  Exhaustion, in turn, rapidly becomes debilitating, and the only ways to heal it are a 5th level spell with a 100gp material component, a rare potion, and long rests.

This is *in addition to* the optional rule that @Gandalfmeansme pointed out that just straight-up hits you with a level of exhaustion every day.

One addendum on the bright side for the build:  While this is a pretty hard limit on going forever, the warlock/sorceror also has a decently efficient technique for turning sorcery points into damage.  Eldritch Blast's nature as a cantrip that is augmented by class features means that it's an especially good use for Quickened Spell (2 sorcery points), and Warlocks don't have many ways by default to use those bonus actions.  So you do have to sleep sometimes, but if your constitution save is good enough (and it's worth investing in, given the requirement of concentration) you can still do pretty respectably for yourself even with the only *modestly* egregious number of temp slots you can assemble.

Comment: You cannot twin *eldritch blast*. Twinned Spell requires that the spell is "incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level".

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Technically, you _can_ twin _eldritch blast_ up until you hit 5th level, because before that point the spell only targets one creature. A sorcerer 3/warlock 1 would have access to Twinned Spell and _eldritch blast_ prior to 5th level. But that is a very slender reed, and does little to get at the heart of the question.

Comment: @screamline I know, in an earlier comment to Ben on a now deleted answer, I wrote, "You cannot twin eldritch blast once it gets a second beam."

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Figures. I'm late to the party again!

Comment: @screamline It all went down very quickly, the answer wasn't actually an answer and was deleted swiftly.

Comment: Just because you don't sleep doesn't mean that the "day" doesn't end. If you travel 8 hours, sit up all night, then travel 8 hours the next day, you're still only traveling 8 hours per day. With Xanathar's you can get exhaustion from not sleeping, but without that optional rule there wouldn't even be an exhaustion check.

Answer (score 0):

This does not violate the RAW.

Explicitly, you can CREATE (not refresh) slots with Flexible Casting.  As you pointed out, [the JC tweets](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/11/04/can-a-warlocksorcerer-covert-sorcery-points-to-warlock-spell-slots/) support that RAI.

The Sage Advice tweet still leaves open whether the slots created are "Pact Magic Slots" or "Spellcasting Slots".  The exact language is:

> Multiclassing: Spell slots from Spellcasting and Pact Magic are
>   interchangeable (PH, 164). Flexible Casting cares about slot level.

That is a non-answer.  It goes on to say:

> Multiclassing/Flexible Casting/Pact Magic: Sorcery points can create a
>   slot that's used with Pact Magic. It's not a "warlock slot."

So, I read that as "you can make Pact Magic short refresh slots" using those sorcery points.