# Is a player character required to engage in downtime activity?

Tags: dnd-5e, downtime

This question was [inspired by a scenario](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78918/22566), where a character could use *Elven trance* and any number of short rests *but no long rests*. Based [on this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78958/22566), I have a follow up question.

By the rules-as-written, is a player character **required** to engage in *downtime* activity?

Another way to ask the question is (per @SorcererQzot's comment) **"Do characters actually have to stop adventuring between adventures?"** since this question is based the discussions at the link.

[Downtime Activities](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=70) (p. 70, Basic Rules)

> Between adventures, the DM might ask you what your character is doing
> during his or her downtime. Periods of downtime can vary in duration,
> but **each downtime activity requires a certain number of days to
> complete before you gain any benefit, and at least 8 hours of each day
> must be spent on the downtime activity for the day to count**. The days
> do not need to be consecutive. If you have more than the minimum
> amount of days to spend, you can keep doing the same thing for a
> longer period of time, or switch to a new downtime activity. (The listed
> pursuits are crafting, recuperating, practicing a profession,
> researching, training).

There are a variety of things that a character can do during downtime, but is the actual taking of downtime **required**?

Taking a Short Rest is a period of downtime that seems to be an exception to the general case made above: if you want a Short Rest you have to be in a special "downtime" (at least 1 hour long per [Basic Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=70), p. 70) but it can occur in the middle of an adventure, and in the middle of the adventuring day.

Beyond that "in the field" downtime (which looks like an outlier) what is the **hard requirement** for downtime?

Answers must cite the rules as written, since the original question was raised in a pure RAW context.

---

Why is the Short Rest an outlier?  Because "Adventurers can take short rests in the midst of an adventuring day" while the bulk of Downtime Activity happens *between adventuring days*. (p. 70 - 71, [Basic Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=71)).

Answer (score 10):

First off RAW gives the referee the authority to decide whether downtime activities are required.

> Between adventures, the DM **might ask** you what your character is
> doing during his or her downtime

In the PHB on page 187, we have a rule requiring the player to choose a lifestyle for their character and pay the appropriate expenses.

> Between adventures, **you choose a particular quality of life and pay
> the cost** of maintaining that lifestyle, as described in chapter 5.
>
> Living a particular lifestyle doesn't have a huge effect on your
> character, but your lifestyle can affect the way other individuals and
> groups react to you. For example, when you lead an aristocratic
> lifestyle, it might be easier for you to influence the nobles of the
> city than if you live in poverty.

If your referee keeps strict track of time between adventure this expense can add up. If the income from adventuring doesn't cover it then the player may have to have their character do something in between adventures i.e. downtime activities to cover their expenses.

Now the lowest lifestyle is Wretched which cost nothing per day. However the description of Wretched is.

> You live in inhumane conditions. With no place to call home, you
> shelter wherever you can, sneaking into barns, huddling in old crates,
> and relying on the goad graces of people better off than you. A
> wretched lifestyle presents abundant dangers. Violence, disease, and
> hunger follow you wherever you go. **Other wretched people covet your
> armor, weapons, and adventuring gear, which represent a fortune by
> their standards**. You are beneath the notice of most people.

While there no direct mechanical consequence of living a Wretched lifestyle, the part highlighted in bold give the referee ample authority per RAW to make the character's life a hell between adventures. The character would win at first but likely be worn down by the incessant attacks and interruptions.

So while engaging in downtime activities is not specifically required, it would not be smart not to at least do something to insure a decent lifestyle..

Comment: Yeah, in my experience, players never want to take downtime. They want to spend every second adventuring BUT they also want all the benefits of downtime at the same time. Also if you're actually running a campaign then there will be overarching villains, who are always busy with villainy. So any time spent "down" is time the arch villain is getting ahead of the party (in their perception). And some adventures don't provide a gap e.g. ToD. So in my experience Downtime is just a myth.

Comment: @geoidesic That has been my experience with published adventures as well--they drive characters from one plot point to the next with no opportunity for breaks, with one particular exception: Dungeon of the Mad Mage. There's no actual pressing crisis that the characters are aware of, and no Big Bad who is up to Nefarious Deeds that will Imperil the World. Just a big dungeon ripe for exploring. It's the only official adventure that really leaves space for players to take some downtime and not feel like it doesn't make sense. But I've played/run non-official adventures that did include downtime.

Comment: @geoidesic That's a matter of GMing style. I usually run campaigns in which the world isn't constantly in jeopardy and PCs have plenty of time between adventures to work on downtime activities - and if they don't have anything they want to work on, I can easily timeskip to the day when the next adventure hook _does_ turn up.

Answer (score 4):

The closest RAW on requiring downtime I can find is from PHB p.187:

> When starting a new adventure, the DM might simply declare that a
>   certain amount of time has passed and allow you to describe in general
>   terms what your character has been doing. At other times, the DM might
>   want to keep track of just how much time is passing as events beyond
>   your perception stay in motion. [PHB p.187]

So downtime only "might" be "required." The PHB lists several "Downtime Activities" on page 187 and the DMG on pages 128-131 lists even more. They are all activities that take hours or even days to complete and therefore are only necessary when players engage in protracted activities outside the parameters of planned encounters.

BUT NOTE that PHB p.186 states that a *short rest* is defined as "a period of **downtime**" and a *long rest* as "a period of extended **downtime**." Therefore, one could argue that RAW indeed requires downtime whenever the party spends or restores hit dice.

ALSO NOTE that *Training* (a reward detailed on DMG p.231) **does in fact require** the use of downtime, but the occurrence of *Training* in a campaign is optional unless you're using the variant rule found on DMG p.131, *Training To Gain Levels*.

Oh, and I think that D&D Adventurers' League might force registered Dungeon Masters to track each players' downtime days and activities performed during those days, but even then I believe that the spending of those accumulated downtime days is at the players' option.

Comment: I already addressed the Short Rest bit; Basic Rules and PHB agree completely on how Short Rests fit into the game.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes and No**. No they do not have to engage in downtime activity, but yes a long rest does occur automatically. Unless downtime activity can be defined as anything not strenuous or combat related.

[Sage Advice exchange with Mike Mearls](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/03/long-rest-and-sleep/)

Initial tweet

> @mikemearls Does this mean that every 8 hrs you automatically complete a long rest if you have spent less than 1hr of that time fighting?

his response

> Mike Mearls ‎@mikemearls
>   @RodneyWade2 combat or other strenuous activity - travel, any work, etc. IIRC, you can get the benefits of a long rest only once per day.

Mike Mearls only says you get the benefits of a long rest once per day and does not refute the automatic triggering of a long rest if there have been 8 consecutive hours uninterrupted by fighting.

He then says it must be include 6 hours of sleeping (or I guess 4 trance hours for elves.)

Comment: I see your target, in terms of does a long rest trigger automatically (a point I raised in one of the comments in that other question) but I don't see strong justification for that being a rule.

Comment: It's the closest I have in that mearls ruled that 8 hours triggers a long rest. For a raw justification, it's the same as on the other thread with regard to using sage advice as raw.

Comment: I read the tweets and didn't see it saying quite what you saw in terms of the triggering.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, how do you read it? It seems that Wade asks about 8 hours automatically completing a long rest if not fighting for more than an hour and Mearls seems to confirm the question and adds strenuous activity to the list of activities that can't take more than an hour. He does not deny that 8 hours of no combat or strenuous activity automatically completes the long rest. - also happy to take this to chat if not appropriate in comments.

Comment: @NautArch You're confusing a lack of denial with a confirmation.  He did not confirm anything, and his denial seems to me to be due to missing the key point of the question ("automatically") vs. what Mearls seems to have interpreted it as ("what things interrupt the long rest?").  Based on his answer it seems more likely that Mearls assumed the question was asking about what actions interrupt a long rest.

Comment: If you aren't doing strenuous (specifically nothing more strenuous than reading,talking, eating, standing watch for no more than 2 hours) activity, then (and only then) you are by Rules definition "resting". If you have 8 hours consecutive where 7 of them were resting, and you haven't had a long rest yet, you have just taken a long rest. Now, "automatic" is a weird word choice, as the DM has to know what you are doing or not doing. But, if they don't do anything during downtime, doing nothing is resting.

Comment: @LegendaryDude, I'm not denying that Mearls didn't confirm that automatic trigger, but he absolutely had an opportunity to do so (and maybe that's why his rulings aren't official) and did not. Neither the tweet nor Mearls' response address clarification on it, but he does seem to confirm that as long as you haven't done anything strenuous or engaged in combat for 8 hours, you've done a long rest. J. A. Streich is looking at it through the same glasses as I am. Without clarification by Mearls, this seems to be the interpretation if you don't try to figure out what Mearls was "likely" answering.

Comment: FYI: The scenario which triggered this question involves a peripatetic elf actively avoiding a long rest. She intentionally performs strenuous activity throughout her day, to carefully avoid triggering a DM's declaration of an automatic long rest. Please see the other question for details, to avoid rehashing all the same issues here.

Comment: @SorcererQzot, I don't want to get into a long comment section again, but if the elf is choosing to perform strenuous activity throughout her day, then I think that's very similar to a Forced March. While built to only need a 4 hour trance to rest, she would still suffer penalties for non-stop activity (which is similar in nature to a forced march) and have to roll Constitution saves or suffer exhaustion penalties (page 181 PHB)

Comment: She is performing exactly as much strenuous activity as adventurers exploring a dungeon and engaging in periodic combat?

Comment: That's an interesting point. In order not to enter "forced march" level of activity, you can't do strenuous activity for more than 8 hours/day. Include your 4 hours of trance-sleep, and you now have 12 hours to fill with combat/normal movement, etc. It seems that even with taking short rests, you'd end up spending more than 8 hours in strenuous activity and trigger an exhaustion check.

Answer (score 2):

In the section, **Between Adventures**, pg 88 of [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf),

> Between trips to dungeons and battles against ancient evils, adventurers need time to rest, recuperate, and prepare for their next adventure. Many adventurers also use this time to perform other tasks, such as crafting arms and armor, performing research, or spending their hard-earned gold.

Adventurers are not required to perform tasks beyond resting, recuperating, and preparing for their next adventure.

Comment: Did you click on the link in my question about the scenario?  Oh, wait, you asked that question about dairy products. :-)  This question has to do with the validity of the never ending adventure day in KRyan's response to your question.  That means that the rule might be that you don't need to prepare for your next adventure if you are in the neverending adventure day.  A different flavor of cheese, but it's in the shop right next to the Cheddar and the Cambembert.

Comment: Oh! I clicked on your first link, because that one sounded interesting. :D I misread your question as "Are characters required to carry out a downtime *activity* during their downtime" whereas you are actually asking "Do characters actually have to stop adventuring between adventures". Do I understand that correctly now?

Comment: That is a decent paraphrase.