# Can a Target of Nightmare Haunting be woken up to break the effect?

Tags: dnd-5e

This arises from discussions in comments on the question: [How can a party defend against the Dream Haunting action of a Night Hag?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80059/how-can-a-party-defend-against-the-dream-haunting-action-of-a-night-hag) .

The wording could either it lasts the duration the Night Hag is in contact with the target, or as long as the Hag is touching someone who is asleep. Based on Rules as Written, does waking up the victim end the effect of a Nightmare Haunting attack of a Night Hag?

Answer (score 4):

Minutes after posting the question here, I check my twitter feed to find Mike Mearls answered my question. So here it is:

> [S]leep is needed to start contact, but not to maintain. hope you have protection from good and evil

https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/730835359110553600

Comment: Unfortunately, Mearls tweets aren't generally considered RAW. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78990/what-is-the-source-defining-what-is-raw