# How does flexible casting interact with itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spell-slots

As I find builds about the Coffeelock (for peoples who doesn't know, it's a build that allows you to have an infinite amount of 5th level spells slot RAW, involving a sorcerer multiclassing in warlock), I turned out asking myself a question:

How does flexible casting interact with itself?

To be clear, I want to know if you can turn created spell slots into sorcery points RAW (which could mean you have an infinite source of sorcery points if you need to do metamagic with your infinite spells).

Comment: Are you talking [about this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78918/22566) ?  Or [this](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=22600207&postcount=11) ?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast technicaly I mention the Coffeelock only to give context to my question, it's not the central point of it. But it's more of the second option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109845/discussion-between-hellsaint-and-thomas-markov).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The flexible casting ability has no memory of where the spell slots came from (until you go to sleep).<sup>1</sup>

[Flexible casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#FontofMagic) (PHB, pg. 101) simply states:

> You can use your sorcery points to gain additional spell slots, or sacrifice spell slots to gain additional sorcery points.

So sure, you may burn slots created from sorcery points to get sorcery points. Note, this *always results in a net loss of resources*. I expend 7 sorcery points to gain a 5th level slot, then burn that slot to gain 5 sorcery points. Spell slots always cost *a greater number of sorcery points* than the slot's level, but a slot can only return a number of sorcery points *equal to the slot's level*. Of course, a net loss of resources doesn't mean much when your resources are functionally unbounded.

---

<sup>1</sup>Flexible casting does specify, "Any spell slot you create with this feature vanishes when you finish a long rest."

Comment: Of course, 'net loss' doesn't matter a lot when you never take a long rest, and have several hundred 5th level spell slots built up.

Comment: @SanfordBassett It also doesn't matter if the DM just winks and lets you cast all the spells you want. It does matter when playing the game with people who are paying attention.

Comment: @MarkWells Now that depends on the kind of campaign you're playing, now doesn't it? When prep time isn't an issue, and a DM isn't going to interrupt downtime in an attempt to prevent an exploit from becoming extremely powerful (which, if they're doing this, why didn't they just ban the exploit in the first place?) then there's no practical limits to the number of spells and sorcery points that can be used, barring the fact that you can only get 5 points with a bonus action.