# Does anything stop a sorcerer stockpiling spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, spell-slots, rests

A Sorcerer converts all their slots to 1st level, then they go to bed for the night. Is there any reason why they wouldn't still have those slots when they wake up in the morning?

Comment: The true version of this: [Does this character concept involving never taking a long rest and converting spell slots to sorcery points (aka coffeelock) violate RAW?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78918)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Your spell slots are all reset

In the description for the [sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) class is this text:

> Creating Spell Slots. You can transform unexpended sorcery points into one spell slot as a bonus action on your turn. The Creating Spell Slots table shows the cost of creating a spell slot of a given level. You can create spell slots no higher in level than 5th.
>
> Any spell slot you create with this feature vanishes when you finish a long rest.

As such, all your extra level one spell slots will vanish after a long rest.

Comment: Good on ya mate, knew I was missing something

Comment: @Non-novelist If you want a rules legal way to get more spell slots than you should have, try a google search for Coffeelock.

Comment: exactly where the question came from haha