# Can an elf warlock with the Aspect of the Moon eldritch invocation still trance?

Tags: dnd-5e, rests, elf, eldritch-invocations, sleep

The [Eldritch Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations) "Aspect of the Moon" from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (pg. 56) provides you with the benefit of no longer needing to sleep:

> #### Aspect of the Moon
>
> *Prerequisite: Pact of the Tome feature*
>
> You no longer need to sleep and can't be forced to sleep by any means. To gain the benefits of a long rest, you can spend all 8 hours doing light activity, such as reading your Book of Shadows and keeping watch.

[Elves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/elf#ElfTraits) do not sleep; they "trance" (from the PHB, pg. 23):

> #### Trance
>
> Elves don’t need to sleep. Instead, they meditate deeply, remaining semiconscious, for 4 hours a day. (The Common word for such meditation is “trance.”) While meditating, you can dream after a fashion; such dreams are actually mental exercises that have become reflexive through years of practice. After resting in this way, you gain the same benefit that a human does from 8 hours of sleep.

If I have an elven warlock, does gaining the Aspect of the Moon invocation override the need to trance? Can an elven warlock still trance if they want to (since [elves can gain the benefits of a long rest in 4h if they trance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48413/35259), but presumably not if they don't trance as per Aspect of the Moon)? Or is it the case that, because trancing is not sleeping, this invocation does nothing for an elf?

Comment: Related on [Must elves take a long rest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78871/must-5e-elves-take-a-long-rest)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## The elf can choose to use Trance or Aspect of the Moon

The language from the Invocation says (emphasis mine)

> **can** spend all 8 hours...

This suggests that it is a choice to utilize that versus the standard long rest option for the character.

### The Functional Differences

**Aspect of the Moon** gives you the option to be awake and aware for the full 8 hours to gain the benefits of a long rest.

**Trance** gives you the option to shut down for just 4 hours for in order to gain the benefits of a Long Rest - but you are not aware for those 4 hours while in the trance. See the printed [Sage Advice](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) for reference to this change:

> If an elf meditates during a long rest (as described
> in the Trance trait), the elf finishes the rest after only 4
> hours. A meditating elf otherwise follows all the rules for
> a long rest; only the duration is changed.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, they can still Trance

*Aspect of the Moon* doesn't eliminate the ability for a character to sleep, it simply eliminates their *need* to sleep, or any ability for them to be *forced* to sleep, like with the *Sleep* spell.

It would similarly stand to reason that even if there were an interaction between Elven "Trancing" and the effects of *Aspect of the Moon*, no part of *Aspect of the Moon* would prevent the elf from Trancing instead of staying awake the whole duration, should they choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

### Elves with the Aspect of the Moon do not need to trance.

Both the Aspect of the Moon and Trance give you ways to spend a long rest, and both are options in addition to the standard rules for a long rest, as neither one says that you *can't* sleep. Each time you take a long rest, you choose which option you want to use.

Comment: Mechanically I think you have it right, however there is a fundamental difference between sleep and trance as detailed in several previous books as well as Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes (iirc). A DM could easily rule that they are different *enough* that an elf would still need to trance. Personally I think these rulings add a difference to the races as opposed to just the normal pointy-eared humans I constantly see played at tables.