# Can a warlock with the Aspect of the Moon eldritch invocation choose to sleep whenever they want?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations, sleep

Aspect of the Moon, an [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) for the Pact of the Tome warlock, grants this benefit:

> You no longer need to sleep and can't be forced to sleep by any means.

This seems to leave open the option to sleep if the warlock wants to. Normally characters (or real people) can't just decide to fall asleep, though; they have to be sleepy/tired. But presumably the warlock does not get this kind of sleepy, ever, at least not so much that they'd need to sleep.

**If a warlock wants to go to sleep for some reason, how does this work? Can they just choose to fall asleep at any time (if it's quiet enough, etc.), despite not needing to sleep?**

---

Why this matters: Apart from role playing or quest/plot related reasons, there is at least one mechanical reason to sleep: *Dream* spell allows a lengthy conversation between two creatures on the same plane, but the target of the spell must be asleep. A warlock with the Aspect of the Moon would need to know to go to sleep at the right time, but this can be easily arranged via *Sending* spell or a mundane letter or a pre-agreed time.

Comment: Probably related: [Can an elf warlock with the Aspect of the Moon eldritch invocation still trance?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131644)

Comment: Yeah, that question was the one that made me realize this invocation says "can't be forced to sleep" instead of "can't sleep", and the invocation is coming up in a campaign very soon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### You can sleep if you want.

“Does not need” is not the same thing as “cannot”. This is evident from the feature’s use of both phrases.

You *cannot* be forced to sleep. This clearly means that no external force can cause you to be put to sleep.

In contrast, you *do not need* sleep, but this does not restrict your ability to do so. It simply means that you do not suffer any negative complications from insomnia.

As a DM, I generally just let my players sleep when they want, unless there is some extenuating circumstance preventing it, such as being in a rainstorm without shelter, or they just woke up from a long rest.

Comment: Is there some rules for "my players sleep when they want" or is that just your assumption? You only put it in the last sentence but I belive it is quite significant as a person cannot just force themselves to sleep on command. For example if my players want to be asleep to trick prison guards or someone I say they fake it and they have to roll for it, because they cannot fall asleep on command even if they have some time to prepare. They have to feel tired to sleep.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130447/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-findusl).

Answer (score -3):

I think 'what sleep is' the problem.
So the unique thing about sleep is that its unconscious enforced on you by your body and you can fight it mentally.(to a point)

So when you fall asleep you STOP resisting it as apposed to 'START sleeping'

So if its ENFORCED by your body, Aspect of the Moon prevents this ENFORCEMET , it wont happen even if you stop resisting.
Its like an eternal insomnia, no matter how long you lie their tossing and turning, you just cant sleep.

So as it isnt a "choice" so you cant choose to sleep.

Comment: Welcome to RPG SE. Those downvotes are probably, because here answers are expected to be backed up by the rules, or actual play experience concerning the question issue, or something else more substantial than opinions or speculation. Don't be discouraged! Also, read the help section.